# Возможно ли изменить адрес в браузерной строке в таком случае?

Tags: jquery, браузер, пути

Всем здравствуйте!
Скажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли сделать следующее: есть страница http://name.ru/cat/1.html. На этой странице есть ссылка на другую страницу http://name.ru/cat/2.html#hash. При переходе по ссылке естественно в браузерной строке адрес отображается как http://name.ru/cat/2.html#hash. Так вот возможно ли, чтобы при переходе по ссылке в браузерной строке адрес отображался без решетки #hash? Благодарю за комментарии!

Comment: какой конечный url вы хотите видеть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону HTML5 History API. Пример использования для вашего случая:

```
history.replaceState({}, '', location.href.replace(location.hash, ''))
```

Здесь текущее состояние истории заменяется на тот же url, но с вырезанными параметрами. Однако от перехода к якорю это не избавит. Для этого понадобится либо изначально открывать страницу без якоря, либо перезагружать её после замены состояния.

**UPD**: Перехват и замена url.

```
$('.target-link').click(function(e) {
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr('href'),
        sharpIndex = targetUrl.indexOf('#');

  if (sharpIndex >= 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = targetUrl.substr(0, sharpIndex);
  }
});
```

Comment: Верно. Вы можете перехватывать клик по ссылке, брать её целевой адрес, убирать якорь и вручную навигировать на страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью javascript убирать. Где-то мне такой jquery код попадался:

```
$('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(e){
      var anchor = $(this);
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
         scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top-100
      }, 1000);
      e.preventDefault();
   });
```

Или можно как [здесь](http://expange.ru/e/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C_(JavaScript)) советуют.

Comment: в вопросе ссылка на _другую страницу_, а не просто на якорь